# Is possible to set and read cookie in iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, cookies

I'm working on an application which uses iframe (Bigcommerce app... Argh!!!). I realised that cookie does not get saved inside the iframe. However outside the iframe it works fine. 
I have searched online but I couldn't find any article about cookie and iframe.

This is my code `setcookie('userID', $user_id, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");`

Any idea? thanks

Comment: is the iframe url on the same domain

Comment: nope! different urls

Comment: then no. cookies are domain specific

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought. Was hoping for some kind of trick. Thanks though

Comment: You can use PHPSESSID on cross-domains though http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php pretty sure.

Comment: a trick all te hacks in the world would love ;-) sorry nope,

Comment: @Dagon sure about that? I did try that once, few months ago actually. I take it that you're commenting on my use of PHPSESSID ?

Comment: These _third party cookies_ (those cookies that are read/set inside the iframe on the external domain) will work providing the user has "third party" cookies enabled in their browser, which is the default in most modern browsers these days. However, many users do disable third party cookies (since they are predominantly only used for tracking/advertising), so they cannot be relied on.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do you mean by "You can use PHPSESSID on cross-domains"? "PHPSESSID" is just a cookie like any other. (Unless you pass the `SID` in the URL in order to physically pass the session ID to another domain - but that's not the same thing?)

Comment: @w3dk the end of my comment read as: *"pretty sure"*. This doesn't mean "100% certain". I'm surprised as to how far you went back for this *lol*. Where did you dig up from, a Google search for a related question today?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, a Google search for a related question - although I wasn't specifically searching SO. (Can't just remember what I searched for exactly, but this page was surprisingly high in the results! A year and a bit isn't too bad! _lol_)

Comment: @w3dk *lol*, you're telling me! Well... I guess I was wrong. I did Google that afterwards about cross-domain coding and yeah.. I was wrong ;-) Oh well... live and learn as the saying goes ;-)